# Find intersection/frequency of a word in multiple file

Tags: php, frequency

```
<?php

$wordFrequencyArray = array();

function countWordsfrequency($filename) {  
global $wordFrequencyArray;

$contentoffile = (file_get_contents($filename));

$wordArray = preg_split('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', $contentoffile, -1, NO_EMPTY);


foreach (array_count_values($wordArray) as $word => $count) {
      if (!isset($wordFrequencyArray[$word])) $wordFrequencyArray[$word] = 0;
        $wordFrequencyArray[$word] += $count;
    }
}


$filenames = array('file1.txt', 'file2.txt','file3.txt','file4.txt');
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    countWordsfrequency($filename);
}



print_r($wordFrequencyArray);

?>
```

This is the my code to find the frequency of each word in multiple files and print them.Now what i want to do is check find intersection that which word occurs in which files .For example if there is a word "stack" i want to print in which files it occurs and its frequency which i think i have already calculated.

Final result should be like the frequency followed by in which files that word occurs.

How should i proceed with it? Should i check it in the for loop in the `countWords` function itself.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save a little more information. I am going to shy away from using classes because it seems like you do not need anything too robust.

```
<?php
$wordFrequencies = array();

function countWordsFrequency($filename) {  
  global $wordFrequencies;
  $contentoffile = (file_get_contents($filename));
  $wordArray = preg_split('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', $contentoffile, -1, NO_EMPTY);

  foreach (array_count_values($wordArray) as $word => $count) {
    $wordFreqInfo = $wordFrequencies[$word];
    if (!isset($wordFreqInfo)) {
      $wordFreqInfo = array();
      $wordFreqInfo['total'] = 0;
      $wordFreqInfo['files'] = array();
      $wordFrequencies[$word] = $wordFreqInfo;
    }

    // If this is the first occurence of this word in the file, start a count.
    if (!isset($wordFreqInfo['files'][$filename]))
      $wordFreqInfo['files'][$filename] = 0;
    }

    // Increment counts for both the total and the file.
    $wordFreqInfo['total'] += $count;
    $wordFreqInfo['files'][$filename] += $count;
  }
}

$filenames = array('file1.txt', 'file2.txt','file3.txt','file4.txt');
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
  countWordsFrequency($filename);
}

print_r($wordFrequencies);
?>
```